# Why Facebook API always returns Email Id when the privacy status is private?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook API for both public and private account. It always returns email id regardless of privacy status. Is there any possible to not return email when the privacy status is private??

Comment: If you authenticate the Facebook App then why will it matter whether its private or public.

Comment: I need to differentiate the public and private account

Comment: There is no such thing as a public or private account. Users can specify who can see what on multiple different properties. And the email privacy settings applies to what other users is gets shown to in the UI. With the API, you explicitly asked the user to grant your app access to their email address - would not make much sense if any privacy settings overruled that explicit permission at this point.